# Angular 6 template + Bootstrap 4 Accordian not working

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get Bootstrap 4 Accordian component to work in an Angular 6 template. The "collapse" and "show" just won't work. I am aware there is another implemention that uses the ngbCollapse directive from ng-bootstrap, but I can't use that implementation. The ngbTemplate tag is read-only and I'd like to add an input text area there. Therefore I would like to use the original implementation itself.

I just copied and pasted the code from the Accordian example into the template, and even that doesn't work. When clicking on the link to expand or collapse, nothing happens.

My code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="accordion">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </button>
    </h5>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </button>
    </h5>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone else have issues with this? Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I have used ngx-bootstrap with success:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion I don't really understand your point why you cannot use ng-bootstrap either. The template content can be dynamic, what is the matter with it?

Comment: I tried adding an "input" tag in the ng-template, and it wouldn't work. I will give ngx-bootstrap a shot. Thanks.